# Check if an array is ribbed

Tags: c, arrays

One one-dimensional array is called ribbed, if every element who has a predecessor and successor is either strictly greater than the two of them(both the predecessor and the successor) or strictly less than the both of them. For a one-dimensional array, with length n(2 < n < 100) find out if the array is ribbed or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main ()
 {

     int n, i, j;
     int check=0;
     scanf ("%d", &n);
     if (n<2 || n>100)
     {
         printf("Invalid input");
     }
     j=n;
     int m[j];

         for (j=0; j<n; j++)
         {
             scanf ("%d", &m[j]);

         }
         for (i=0; i<n-2; i++)
         {
             if ( ( ( m[i] < m[i+1] ) && ( m[i+1] > m[i+2] ) )  ||  
             ( ( m[i] > m[i+1] ) && ( m[i+1] < m[i+2] ) ) )
         {
               check=1;
         }
              else check=0;

         }


     if (check==1 )
         {
             printf ("YES");
         }
     else if (check==0)
         {
             printf ("NO");
         }

     return 0;



 }
```

This is the result I get for my test cases http://prntscr.com/53zoc3. 
Each time I submit my answers I get a different result though, for example the third and fourth case  http://prntscr.com/53zt79. 
I was just wondering if I could get opinion on what I need to fix for the second case problem and if in general my code seems good. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I do not see where the array is initialized.

Secondly you are trying to access memory beyond the array in the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (((m[i] < m[i + 1]) && (m[i + 1] > m[i + 2]))
            || ((m[i] > m[i + 1]) && (m[i + 1] < m[i + 2]))) {
        check = 1;
    } else
        check = 0;
}
```

If `i` is equal to `n - 2` then `m[i+2]` will be equivalent to `m[n]`. However the valid range of indices is `0, n - 1`

Also you neeed to interrupt the loop if check is set to 0.

And if the input does not satisfy condition

```
if (n < 2 || n > 100)
    printf("Invalid input");
```

the program should ends.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `check` after the for loop is set only by the check of the last (but one) element of the array.  But earlier elements may not pass the ribbed test.

If any element in the loop fails the "ribbed" test, you need to stop testing any more elements, because you know at that point the array is not ribbed.

So add a break to the failure case:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (((m[i] < m[i + 1]) && (m[i + 1] > m[i + 2]))
            || ((m[i] > m[i + 1]) && (m[i + 1] < m[i + 2]))) {
        check = 1;
    } else {
        check = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did have a break there in the previous version of my code, but this is what happens when I submit it http://prntscr.com/53zzly and I can't understand why.

Comment: Sorry, if you post code different from what you actually use, how on earth do you expect us to work out what the problem is?!

Comment: I am currently working with this code, just had the break added at the same place as you suggested. Not working with different code, sorry if I expressed myself incorrectly.

Comment: Yes you are working with different code. The code you submitted uses `break` (you say) but the code in your question does not. We cannot guess what code you are actually using.

Comment: Could you please stop PMSing all over my question. I said that whenever I add break to my code I get this result http://prntscr.com/53zzly which is NOT helping me in any way. Thank you.

Comment: We don't know what code you're submitting. You haven't shown it to us. Post the code you are actually submitting, then you might get help. The code in the question a) is missing the break b) does not initialise the m array and c) accesses elements off the end of the array.